# Como dar update em uma tabela diferente com um dado de outra tabela em PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, libcurl, phpmyadmin

Pessoal Tenho uma tabela pagseguro, e nela tenho um codigo de indenficação de cada transação, 
ao receber os dados da atualizacao, quero pegar os dados e inserir em update em outra tabela do banco sendo que 1 dos campos não tem na outra tabela ou seja

na tabela que vou atualizar, tem usuario e valor, mas n tem a de codigos, e para definir se realmente e aquele usuario q vai receber o codigo e não duplicadamente, preciso que seja especifico daquele codigo... alguem poderia me ajudar? 
exemplo :

USUARIO 1 comprou 30 reais, codigo da compra xx3

quando a compra for aprovada, vai receber do codigo compra xx3 o retorno de compra e liberação desses 30 reais de credito, e vai inserir na tabela ( os 30 reais) de credito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso parece simples.

1) Existem 2 tabelas. Uma possui usuário, valor. Na outra existe usuário, valor e código.

2) Insira a coluna 'código' na primeira tabela, assim as duas ficam iguais, você pode facilmente inserir essa coluna por um comando simples SQL ou por phpmyadmin.

3) Agora, basta pegar o valor de uma tabela, por meio do PHP e inserir na outra. Você deve fazer isso com PHP (variáveis) e um simples comando SQL (update).

4) Utilize o PDO para conectar e gerenciar seus banco de dados com PHP.

OBS: mostre suas tentativas de código para que possamos ajudar melhor.

Até.

Comment: no caso ambas tem a coluna de usuario, e creditos, isso não bastaria sendo que meu sistema n permite criar um usuario duplicado ?

Comment: Antes de adicionar o valor com o comando SQL na outra tabela, você deve utilizar um if ($usuario1 == $usuario2) {código..} para verificar se os dois são iguais. Você pode transferir apenas o valor referente ao código, para a tabela que não tem.

Comment: e uma boa hipotese de se fazer tmb. vou testar essa ai Stefano Valeu! Jaja retorno pra da um alô